# Syntax error in httpd.conf (Apache, MacOS X Yosemite)

Tags: macos, apache

I can't start Apache webserver on Mac. If enter

```
    sudo apachectl start
```

it gives answer

```
    httpd: Syntax error on line 69 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so, 10): Symbol not found: _ap_condition_if_match\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
```

After I commented in httpd.conf this line it gives same error about next one. Probably I have damaged httpd.conf and I used this to solve it:

```
   sudo cp /etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

But it didn't work. When I start apache again it gives same answer. I think I have some damaged version of Apache on my Mac. What's going on and how to solve it? Please help me.

Comment: What does `nm /usr/sbin/httpd | grep _ap_condition_if_match` yield when run from the command line?

Comment: Already solved. Previous owner installed Apache 2.2 via Homebrew. `brew uninstall httpd22` solved this issue.